# Microsoft Excel Add-in Microphone Access

Tags: excel, office-addins, excel-addins

I have built a Microsoft Excel add-in that needs microphone access to work properly, I tested the add-in on Office Web and it works just fine. But when I tried to use it on my Microsoft Excel 2019 Windows version, it gave the following error on the task pane

`InvalidAccessError at Anonymous function (https://localhost:3000/taskpane.js:2292:7)`.

I have tried to enable the microphone for desktop webview since underneath Excel uses the webview to display the add-in but to no avail.

I want to know how to allow microphone access for Excel add-in.

It is important to know I am trying to request access to the microphone through browser javascript API, which should come as part of the webview loaded by Microsoft Excel.